# Default Fonts in Java

Tags: java, windows, fonts

I have some Swing code (written in 1.6 for 1.6) that specifically sets the font in a text area to Courier, but on some Windows systems, this shows up as Arial (the system default?) instead.  Does that mean a font is missing from the system?  What is the behavior Java has when it can't find a font it is looking for?  Does it complain?  Does it log it somewhere?  Does it immediately resort to using the system default?  Is the behavior different between 1.4/1.5/1.6 versions of the JVM?

Has anyone else ever run into this?  I was very surprised to have something different from what I HARDCODED into the application show up in the UI - and only on some systems.  The core issue is that I need a monospaced font style for this particular case, and Arial is not monospaced.  Is there some way to specify a fallback if a certain font is not found?  Something like:

if font is available use "Courier"
else use "monospaced"

???

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if "Courier" is among the results of `GraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames()`

I don't know any built-in mechanism in Java for "`if-unavailable-fallback-to`" behavior.

Comment: I would be really surprised if Courier was missing on any windows system.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article[1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/90057/microsoft-supplied-monospaced-truetype-fonts) the only monospaced TrueType fonts shipped by Microsoft are Courier New and Lucida Sans Typewriter.

Answer (score 0):

It might expect you to specify "Courier New" for Courier. I don't have a Windows system, so I can't verify this.